# Grep: count number of matches per line

Tags: linux, regex

I'm trying to get the number of matches (in this case occurrences of `{` or `}`) in each line of a .tex file.

I know that the `-o` flag returns only the match, but it returns each match on a new line, even combined with the `-n` flag.  I don't know of anything I could pipe this through to count the repeats. The `-c` flag only returns the total number of matches in the entire file - maybe I could pipe one line at a time to grep?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
grep -o -n '[{}]' <filename> | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq -c
```

The output will be something like:

```
3 1
1 2
```

Meaning 3 occurrences in the first line and 1 in the second.

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15366097/3378354 .

Comment: Thanks - google found lots of regex hits on SU, but not that one on SO, which doesn't even seem to have a regex tag.  The `sort` isn't strictly necessary as grep's output is sorted by line number, but I guess it's good practice before `uniq`.

Comment: Probably not tagged `regex` because the regex is the easy part.

Comment: Is it actually necessary to `sort -n`? Doesn't it come out in line number order anyway?

Comment: You are right, `sort -n` is not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: @TomZych, it turned out you were right, but had I known that I might not have asked.  The mental jump from grep to tag:regex was perhaps a bit too much though.

Comment: I thought it was a neat command so I tried it on an existing 5k file that I found on my ubuntu vm. If I am not mistaken, the order of the commands is wrong. It should be `grep -o -n '[{}]' file | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq -c`. `-w1` isn't needed either. The difference is 12 lines vs 118!

Comment: @Vic, thanks for noticing it! The `-w1` option of `uniq` was blocking the comparison to the first character, therefore only working on line numbers of 1 digit. Changing the order, as you suggested, makes it unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

After reading various solutions, I think this is the easiest approach to the problem:

```
while read i; do echo $i |grep -o "matchingString"| wc -l;  done < input.txt
```

Comment: Best solution, in my opinion. Could be even more simplified by reducing by one pipe: `grep -o "matchingString" <<< $i | wc -l`.

Comment: This will be orders of magnitude slower then other options though

Answer (score 2):

Is using `grep` a requirement?  Here’s an alternative:

```
sed 's/[^{}]//g' your_file | awk '{print NR, length }'
```

The `sed` strips out all characters other than `{` and `}`
(i.e., leaving only `{` and `}` characters),
and then the `awk` counts the characters on each line (which are just the `{` and `}` characters). 
To suppress lines with no matches,

```
sed 's/[^{}]//g' your_file | awk '/./ {print NR, length }'
```

Note that my solution assumes (requires) that the strings you are looking for are single characters. 
Moebius’s answer is more easily adapted to multi-character strings. 
Also, neither of our answers
excludes quoted or escaped occurrences of the characters/strings of interest; e.g.,

```
{ "nullfunc() {}" }
```

would be considered to contain four brace characters.

Comment: `grep` wasn't really a requirement, it was just where I started looking for a solution, because it gave me something close.  I've never had a need for awk, so had I not used the answer above I'd have used this as a chance to experiment -- I may still.  What I failed to make clear (but it doesn't affect either answer) is that I wanted to run the script once per bracket, to help me track down a mismatch (in LaTeX source, here for a table) where most pairs occur in a single line.

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you mean by “run the script once per bracket,” but if you want to track down a brace mismatch, you might want to try something like `sed 's/{[^{}]*}//g' your_file | grep –n '[{}]'`, where the `sed` strips out (matched) pairs. If you have nested pairs, use `sed 's/{[^{}]*}//g;s/{[^{}]*}//g;s/{[^{}]*}//g;…' …`, repeating the `s/{[^{}]*}//g` as many times as your deepest nesting.

Comment: I meant execute `sed 's/[^}]//g' your_file | awk '{print NR, length }' and 's/[^{]//g' your_file | awk '{print NR, length }'.  I do indeed have nesting, and working out the deepest level seemed like a chore. Turning many lines into a handful (there are a few cases where the braces only match over multiple lines for valid reasons) worked well (I use jedit which highlights the matching bracket -- for any type of bracket it understands -- so I really did just need to narrow it down).

Answer (score 1):

AWK can do this by itself, piping multiple processes is not necessary.

```
awk '{print NR " " gsub(/[{}]/, "")}'
```

Example:

```
$ printf 'test{}\n abc\n }{{}\n xyz}' | awk  '{print NR " " gsub(/[{}]/, "")}'
1 2
2 0
3 4
4 1
```

The `grep` count option `-c` is a con job. It does not return the total count you expect (it is actually just a line count, not a match count).

```
$ printf 'test{}\n abc\n }{{}\n xyz}' | grep -con "[{}]"
3
```

`awk` can get a total count like this:

```
$ printf 'test{}\n abc\n }{{}\n xyz}' | awk -F"[{}]" '{c+=NF-1} END {print c}'
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can search for the occurrence of a string, show the number of times it was found and the linenumber on which it was found. Here I wanted to see only those lines that have the search string more than once.
As input I'm using man page for ls. I put the search string (here: 'of') in a variable.

```
 s='of'; man ls | awk -v s="${s}" '{ if ($0 ~ s) { k = split($0, ar, s); if (k > 2) { print NR, k-1, $0 }}}' | grep "${s}"
```

Output:

```
32 2        -c     with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of file status information); with -l: show ctime and sort by name; otherwise: sort by ctime, newest first
180 2        The  SIZE  argument  is  an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024).  Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,... (powers of 1000).  Binary prefixes can be used, too: KiB=K,
```

The grep statement is used to colorize the search string (not visible here).